# Setting up virtual networks in vmware workstation 6

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation, virtual-machines, ifconfig

I've been googling this for hours and I seem to be confused. If anybody could give me a link or point me in the right direction it would be appreciated.

I'm using vmware **workstation 6**. I have **three** vm's (all linux). One of those VM's has two network adapters. One connected to my physical internet, and the other network adapter I would like to be connected to the other 2 vm's. **The second network adapter on my 'virtual host' is custom type VMnet2**, and the network adapters on my 2 other VM's are the same (custom type vmnet2).

I read on a website that I need to set the ip for my internal private network within the range of vmnet2, and I did with ifconig. What do I do next? Do I have to change anything in the Virtual Network Editor? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-steve

Answer (score 1):

Does VMnet2 exist on your host? It sounds like the easiest thing for you would be to connect the three that you want to communicate with each other to the hostonly network, and assign them all an IP in the range that hostonly is configured for (or let them get addresses from the DHCP server that VMware installs and enables by default).